# how function 'idx2char' works

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm learning to run a text generation model and here's a func named 'idx2char', but I haven't find any documents or instructions about it online. Maybe it's an inner method written in tensorflow or numpy? I have no idea. And I meet some errors related to it.

```py
print("Input: \n", repr("".join(idx2char[input_example_batch[0]])))
print()
print("Next Char Predictions: \n", repr("".join(idx2char[sampled_indices])))
```

and result is

```
tf.Tensor(
[42  6  1 57 61 43 43 58  1 26 43 42  2  1 57 54 43 39 49  1 58 53  1 58
 46 63  1 51 53 58 46 43 56  6  1 40 53 63  2  0 15 39 52 57 58  1 58 46
 53 59  1 52 53 58  1 57 54 43 39 49 12  1 27  1 58 56 39 47 58 53 56 57
  2  1 51 59 56 42 43 56 43 56 57  2  0 32 46 43 63  1 58 46 39 58  1 57
 58 39 40 40], shape=(100,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([42  6  1 57 61], shape=(5,), dtype=int64)

/Users/apple/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:4: FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
  after removing the cwd from sys.path.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-4f66f6adef79> in <module>
      2 a = input_example_batch[0][0:5]
      3 print(a)
----> 4 b = idx2char[a]
      5 print(b)

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, actually, this is a function defined earlier in the tutorials.